# Is there a way to let Chart.js to round up decimals?

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to let Chart.js to round up decimals?

Sure, i can do it in PHP where i get the numbers.
But maby there is an option in Chart.js to do this?

I have tried nothing, but google search.

What i want is: 2733.33

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChartJS expects the data to be in the format you need when it is fed in; as you mention you'll need to do it in PHP prior to putting it into the data array.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - if you're doing it in PHP, try the 'round' function to as specific as you need it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php